# Preventing chown, chmod and rm -r over sshfs

Tags: sshfs

I recently did a chown on my home dir but forgot I had used sshfs to map a drive on a remote server. :(

Is there a way to make sure no file altering command will "cross over" to the other side? :)

Comment: The whole point of sshfs is to make sure file altering commands happen on the remote end.  Stop using it if you want to keep your typos local.

Comment: That's not what I want. I want "chown & Co." to be aware when they cross over and give a heads up before they do.